# Google Protocol buffer c++ link error when trying to use it in project

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, protocol-buffers, linker-errors

I am trying to get protocol buffer to work but linking problems occurs.

All the errors looks something along like this

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromArray(void const *,int)" (?ParseFromArray@MessageLite@protobuf@google@@QEAA_NPEBXH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ReceiveRequest(bool *)" (?ReceiveRequest@@YAXPEA_N@Z)`

I am using visual studio pro 2013 and this is what I have done:

I compiled the protocol buffer and added the libprotobuf.lib to the project(Add->Existing Item->libprotobuf.lib)

I've added the header files in C/C++ -> General -> "Additional Include Directories"

I have tried to add the library all the different ways I know but I still get these linking errors...

Any idea what I might have done wrong?

// Eric

Comment: you need to reference the .lib in your project by adding the containing directory to the VC++ Directories -> Library Directories. And libprotobuf.lib in the Linker ->Input -> Additional Dependencies

Comment: I have tried that, it gives the same error.

Comment: @Eric make sure you add the libs (as Robot Mess suggested) for *all configurations* (i.e. not just Debug or Release). That has caught me out many times - could be the problem in your case.

Comment: Also make sure you have the correct libs for your architecture (x86 / x64 etc.)

Comment: "All Configurations" are selected and it still produces this error. I got really no clue what might be wrong...

Comment: hmm maybe you're right about the x86 and x64, I will give it a try.

Comment: @Brett You were right about the x86/x64, I was running in x64 but I forgot to compile the protocol buffer as x64 as well. Thanks a lot for the help!
Is there anyway to accept comments as the solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct libraries for your architecture (e.g. x86 / x64).

That has caught me out a few times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the *generated* protocol buffer .cc (and maybe the .h) file (ie the file with the specific getters and setters for your specific proto) in your VS project (ie there has to be a little icon for them in the solution explorer) or else visual studio won't generate the code for it and thus there's nothing to link to.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked a years ago, and already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a dramatically better alternative approach to the problem :)